# Android edit system files

Tags: android, class, permissions, edit

I've recently started working on my first application for android, and I'm a bit stuck. My application uses the CountDownTimer class, which, it seems, malfuncions - CountDownTimer.cancel() doesn't work. I do know how to fix this by modifying the CountDownTimer.java file, but I don't have the permission to do so. I'm working in Android Studio. I couldn't find an explanation online, even though it seems quite a fundamental question, isn't it? Perhaps I'm not using the right terms?

Thank you very much for your help, and I apologize if my question's a bit ignorant haha.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener
    {
        private static final String tag = "Main";
        private MalibuCountDownTimer countDownTimer;
        private long timeElapsed;
        private boolean timerHasStarted = false;
        private Button startB;
        private TextView text;
        private TextView timeElapsedView;

        private final long startTime = 50000;
        private final long interval = 1000;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                startB = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);
                startB.setOnClickListener(this);

                text = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.timer);
                timeElapsedView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.timeElapsed);
                countDownTimer = new MalibuCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
                text.setText(text.getText() + String.valueOf(startTime));
            }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (!timerHasStarted)
                    {
                        countDownTimer.start();
                        timerHasStarted = true;
                        startB.setText("Start");
                    }
                else
                    {

                        countDownTimer.cancel();
                        timerHasStarted = false;
                        startB.setText("RESET");
                    }
            }

        // CountDownTimer class
        public class MalibuCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer
            {

                public MalibuCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval)
                    {
                        super(startTime, interval);
                    }

                @Override
                public void onFinish()
                    {
                        text.setText("Time's up!");
                        timeElapsedView.setText("Time Elapsed: " + String.valueOf(startTime));
                    }

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
                    {
                        text.setText("Time remain:" + millisUntilFinished);
                        timeElapsed = startTime - millisUntilFinished;
                        timeElapsedView.setText("Time Elapsed: " + String.valueOf(timeElapsed));
                    }
            }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried something similar, but it doesn't help. It seems as if the cancel() method doesn't stop the calls to onTick(). Thanks anyway for your help!